# Относительная высота

Tags: html, css

Необходимо, не изменяя **html**, относительно текста внутри task увеличивать height **каждого класса task**. В коде высота task изменяется только по рядам.

```css
body{
    color: white;
}
.container {
    margin-top: 36px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 490px 490px;
    gap: 20px 19px;
    grid-template-rows: min-content;
    width: 1000px;
}

.task {
    width: 490px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: black;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 10px;

}

label {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 16px 52px 51px 20px;
}

.container-for-inp{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 0px 1px 7px 1px;

}

.container-for-inp span,
span.active {

    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;

    position: relative;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    border: 1px solid #5F81B2;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 18px;
}

.description {
    margin-bottom: 19px;
    width: 417px;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="task">
        <label>
            <div>
                <span class="container-for-inp">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga,
                    veniam?</span>
                <div class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque, voluptate
                    quam illum eaque iusto magni molestiae optio neque facere odit quisquam omnis? Ipsam repellat
                    ipsum sint vero quam ea veniam!</div>
            </div>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="task">
        <label>
            <div>
                <span class="container-for-inp">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga,
                    veniam?</span>
                <div class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum, eligendi!
                </div>
            </div>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="task">
        <label>
            <div>
                <span class="container-for-inp">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga,
                    veniam?</span>
                <div class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque, voluptate
                    quam illum eaque iusto magni molestiae!</div>
            </div>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="task">
        <label>
            <div>
                <span class="container-for-inp">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga,
                    veniam?</span>
                <div class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque, voluptate
                    quam illum eaque iusto magni molestiae optio neque facere odit quisquam omnis? Ipsam repellat
                    ipsum sint vero quam ea veniam!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque, voluptate
                    quam illum eaque iusto magni molestiae optio neque facere odit quisquam omnis? Ipsam repellat
                    ipsum sint vero quam ea veniam!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque, voluptate
                    quam illum eaque iusto magni molestiae optio neque facere odit quisquam omnis? Ipsam repellat
                    ipsum sint vero quam ea veniam!</div>
            </div>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: задайте фон вместо .task дочернему label и увидите нужную вам меньшую высоту

Answer (score 0):

В CSS используйте свойство `min-height` для класса task. Это гарантирует, что высота каждого элемента класса task будет как минимум этой величины, но увеличится, если содержимое этого элемента больше этого значения.

Измените стиль `task` так, как показано ниже:

```css
.task {
    width: 490px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: black;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 10px;    /* Минимальная высота */
}
```

Теперь, независимо от того, сколько контента находится внутри каждого блока task, высота блока будет увеличиваться автоматически, чтобы по максимуму содержать содержимое.

Также убедитесь, что общий контейнер может вместить эти блоки. Если вы используете грид или flex, убедитесь, что контейнер также может развернуться, чтобы вместить вложенный контент.

Если вы обнаружили, что ваши существующие стили каким-то образом совместно работают и переопределяют это поведение, попробуйте использовать инструменты разработчика в браузере, чтобы исследовать, какие стили применяются, и выяснить, в чем может быть проблема.

Добавлю, что ваш исходный код уже содержит `min-height`, поэтому, возможно, вы столкнулись с какой-то другой проблемой.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Почему публикация ответов созданных GPT и ChatGPT недопустима?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)

Comment: Я имела ввиду что например высота task второго ряда первого столбца должна была сохранить меньшую высоту чем его соседний task второго ряда второго столбца

Comment: Понял, переделаю